# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 after openConnection()

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm try to use the Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP v1, but when I get the response code after calling openConnection(), "404" error code is returned

```
URL url = new URL(FCM_SEND_ENDPOINT);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
System.out.println("status:" + httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
```

I have check the Project ID in the URL, should be the Project ID in the Firebase Console (Settings --> General --> Project ID)

Firebase Console:

[image: Firebase Console]

https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxxxxxxx/messages:send

#### UPDATED AS ON 29-11-2017

In my case, when I try to connect to FCM, I use the dummy token in the JSON string which cause the "404" error code returned.
 
Detail can refer the link ["HTTP Connection Server Reference And Response Codes"](http://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) provided from Zaigham Raza
After using the real token in the JSON string, I can receive the notification message on my device.

Wrong:
    `{"message":{"notification":{"title":"notification title","body":"message body"},"token":"123"}}`

Correct:
    `{"message":{"notification":{"title":"notification title","body":"message body"},"token":"dwB0YqF......"}}`

Here the sample code

```
public static HttpURLConnection getHTTPConn() throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL(FCM_SEND_ENDPOINT);
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    String token = getAccessToken();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8");
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    return httpURLConnection;
}
//The following code to retrieve the token with Google API Client Library <https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server>
private static String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
    GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
    .fromStream(new FileInputStream("service-account.json"))
    .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
    googleCredential.refreshToken();
    return googleCredential.getAccessToken();
}
public static void sendPushNotificationV1(){
    String result = "";
    try{
        HttpURLConnection conn = getHTTPConn();
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(json.toString());
        wr.flush();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        result = "SUCCESS";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

enjoy~

Comment: Check that the JSON message is properly formatted and contains valid fields (for instance, making sure the right data type is passed in).

Comment: May i know if i just call openConnection() and getResponseCode() from HttpURLConnection will return 404 error code, is it normal?

Comment: Please read this link in bottom you have response code and issues 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: Thank you.

It's seem that the response code not exactly to response code 400 from FCM (Indicates that the request could not be parsed as JSON.) 
My situation is that 
- if i paste the url to browser it return 404 not found
- if use the Legacy HTTP protocol(https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send), after calling openConnection(), get the response code is 200 

It's seem that the url of FCM HTTP v1 is not exist.

Comment: Yes now you check your JSON formatting e.g (in json we have these issues /\ and format that properly  )

Comment: Thanks ..I changed to the topic in JSON  and now it's now working.

Comment: We don't put `[SOLVED]` in question titles. The question being "solved" is indicated by having an answer which is accepted. Normally, given that you solved it on your own, I'd recommend posting your solution as an Answer. However, it sounds like what you did to solve this was make a change in code/data that isn't included in the question. As such, you should either [edit] the question to have enough information such that anyone could find that solution (a [mcve]) (*without* putting the solution in the question) and then add an Answer, which you can accept; or just delete the question.

Comment: @W.Mike should i post answer which i sent you in comments

Comment: @Zaigham Raza Yes, please post the answer and I will update the example & detail in the question tonight. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the JSON message is properly formatted and contains valid fields (for instance, making sure the right data type is passed in).
Please read this link in bottom you have response code and issues.
[HTTP Connection Server Reference And Response Codes](http://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)